# What is the completion of $C[0,1]$ equipped with the integral norm?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Define the norm $\|f\|$ on $C[0,1]$

$$\|f\|=\int_{0}^{1}|f(x)| \text{ }dx.$$

Define $f_n(x)$ as
$$f_n(x)=\begin{cases}
nx & \text{if } 0\leq x\leq  \frac{1}{n}\\
1 & \text{if }\frac{1}{n}<x\leq 1
\end{cases}
$$

Question 1:

I can see from the graph that $f_n$ is converging to a function which is not continuous. But how do I prove that $f_n$ is actually not converging in $C[0,1]$ with respect to this norm.

Question 2:

What is the completion of $C[0,1]$ with respect to this norm? Is it the set of integrable functions defined on $[0,1]$?

Edit:

The sequence $f_n$ is convergent to the function $1$ in this norm.

Comment: That's not a norm, because for $f$ defined as $f(x)=-1$, you have $$\int_0^1 f(x)dx=-1$$

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. I have edited the question.

Comment: Q1.  One way to show that a sequence is not converging in a given norm is to show that it is not a Cauchy sequence.  Q2.  You have a slight misstatement.  It is the set of (equivalence classes of) integrable functions defined on $[0,1]$.  Not "defined on $C[0,1]$".

Comment: Your $f_n$ converges to the constant function $1$ in this norm.

Comment: @GEdgar Thanks for pointing out the misstatement. About your suggestion on Q1: the sequence $f_n$ is Cauchy, so we are powerless.

Comment: Anyway, the completion you get is known as $L^1([0,1])$, and it's almost the space of integrable functions that you suggest, but with one caveat: we have to identify two functions whenever they differ on a set of measure zero. For example the pointwise limit of your $f_n$ and the constant function $1$ are representatives of the same element of $L^1$.

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis  Thanks for pointing out my mistake, $f_n$ indeed converges to $1$ wrt this norm.

Answer (score 2):

If your sequence was meant to show that $C[0,1]$ is not complete in the integral norm, it fails to achieve that goal, because its limit is the constant function $1$. Instead, see [Showing that the space $C[0,1]$ with the $L_1$ norm is incomplete](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/156904).

The completion of $C[0,1]$ with respect to the norm $\|f\| = \int_0^1 |f(x)|\,dx$ is the Lebesgue space $L^1[0,1]$. The proof of this fact consists of two independent parts, which are already discussed here:

1. [Continuous functions are dense in $L^1[0,1]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/226049)
2. [$L^1[0,1]$ is complete](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/808521/l1-is-complete-in-its-metric)